# Wie lautet dieser bairische Text auf Hochdeutsch?

Tags: dialect, bavarian, listening-comprehension

Die Süddeutsche Zeitung berichtet unter der Überschrift »Firma sucht: für unsan Haufa: Oan(e) fias Biroh« von einer Stellenanzeige im Dialekt.
Ich habe herzlich gelacht, aber nur die Hälfte verstanden. 
Könnte jemand die Ausschreibung wortwörtlich, aber verständlich ins Hochdeutsche übertragen?

Ihr findet die bairische Anzeige als Bild in [diesem Artikel](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/bayern/dialekt-stellenanzeige-unternehmen-niederbayern-1.4232087) der Süddeutschen Zeitung.
Dort wird auch auf die Anzeige der Firma bei Facebook verlinkt.

Comment: Wenn du fragen möchtest, ob eine solche Frage hier OK ist, ist Meta dafür der richtige Ort.

Comment: @CarstenS Davon ausgehend, dass der Zusatz im Titel nur eine saloppe Formulierung war und es eigentlich um den bairischen Text geht, habe ich die Frage geändert.

Comment: Multiplex, wenn dir die Änderung nicht gefällt, kannst du sie natürlich rückgängig machen.

Comment: Verlinkiungen sind extrem vergänglich. Gute Praxis wäre es, von dem Artikel einen Screenshot zu machen und diesen als Bild hier fest einzubauen.

Comment: @ C.G. - Hätte Philipp mein posting nicht umgeschrieben und dabei nicht Wesentliches getilgt, hättest du lesen können, was ich zum Urheberrecht geschrieben hatte. Auch ein screenshot ist eine Urheberrechtsverletzung. Siehe hierzu den wikipedia-Artikel zu 'Urheberrecht'. Zu deiner Aufforderung siehe den wiki-Artikel zu 'Anstiftung'. Für Laien sind die dortigen Ausführungen ausreichend.

Comment: Mir ging es bei dem edit darum, eine etwaige Diskussion, ob etwas on-topic oder gesetzeskonform ist von der eigentlichen Frage (Übersetzung des Textes) zu trennen. Wie gesagt, wenn dadurch etwas Wichtiges verloren gegangen ist: dafür gibt es die rollback Funktion

Comment: @multiplex   Du brauchst dich vor dem Urheberrecht nicht so zu fürchten. Einen Artikel (oder einen Absatz daraus) abzulichten, um damit eine (mehr oder weniger) wissenschaftliche (oder jedenfalls philologische) Erörterung bestimmter Textspezifika zu ermöglichen, die ohne eine Darstellung des Originaltextes sinnlos oder schwer verständlich würde, wird kein Gericht dieser schönen Republik als Urheberrechtsverletzung werten.

Comment: a) Wenn Du die Hälfte verstanden  hast, solltest Du diese Hälfte selbst beitragen und nicht anderen die Last aufbürden. b) Wenn der Text urheberrechtlich geschützt  ist, dann ist eine nicht autorisierte Übersetzung wohl auch. c) Translation requests of whole texts are here off-topic: Vote to close. @ChristianGeiselmann: Da hast Du aber wohl die letzen Jahre einiges verschlafen. Insbesondere einen Text in Gänze zu übernehmen …

Comment: @userunknown Sorry for the nitpicking, but it's not a _translation request_ (German to English), but a _transcription request_ (Bavarian to Standard German). Hence, it's on-topic, as far as I know.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Auf welche Definition des Begriffs Transkription beziehst Du dich? Für mich ist es eine Übersetzung eines bajuwarischen Dialekts in Hochdeutsch. Transkription wäre etwa die Niederschrift eines Audiotextes oder die Umschrift von Sütterlin in Lateinische Buchstaben.

Comment: @userunknown Du hast recht, _Transkription_ ist wohl der falsche Begriff. Aber _Übersetzung/Translation_ ist meines Erachtens Sprache-zu-Sprache, nicht Dialekt-zu-Hochsprache (die Sprache bleibt gleich). Ich habe mal bei den [Linguisten](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30176/what-is-the-linguistic-term-for-re-writing-a-dialect-text-to-standard-language) angefragt, wie der korrekte Terminus lautet, mal gucken, was passiert :)

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Ist ein Dialekt etwa keine Sprache? Übersetzung ist ein sehr weit gefasster Begriff, Quellcode kann auch in Bytecode oder Maschinensprache übersetzt werden, gesprochene Rede in Gebärdensprache, man sagt "ich übersetze das mal ins Hochdeutsche" wenn sich jemand undeutlich ausdrückt usw., da muss man keinen Linguisten fragen. Gerade in der Fachsprache gibt es oft eigene Benennungstraditionen, die für den Rest der Sprachgemeinschaft nicht verbindlich sind.

Answer (score 4):

Der Ort Malching, in dem die Firma sitzt, liegt in Niederbayern.
Entsprechend handelt es sich vermutlich um den dort gesprochenen Dialekt.
Hier ein Versuch, die Wörter auf Hochdeutsch erkennbar zu machen, mit Anmerkungen in eckigen Klammern.

> Seit 16 Jahren bauen wir Aufzüge, Treppenlifte und Elektrokachal [evtl. -öfen?] und unsere Kunden schätzen uns recht [sehr] sakrisch [stark; von Sakrament].
>
> Aufzugdienst Rottal
>   … bewegend, menschlich!
>
> **Und jetzt brauchen wir für unseren Haufen:**
>   **Eine(n) fürs Büro**
>
> **Bei uns gibts:**
>   - eine Arbeit, wo [bei der] man denken darf, die nicht langweilig wird und wo [bei der] man etwas zu sagen hat
>   - einen sicheren Arbeitsplatz (wir sind keine [Grattler](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grattler)firma [finanziell schwache Firma])
>   - jemanden, der dir zeigt wie es geht, auch wenn du dich noch nicht gleich so auskennst
>   - alles mögliche zu tun
>   - eine Arbeit in einer Firma, die etwas Sinnvolles macht und den Leuten hilft
>   - Lustig sind wir, ehrlich sind wir, Hund [evtl. [gewieft](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/hundling-der/)?] sind wir und wir schauen [achten] auf unsere Leute
>   - eine gute Mannschaft, die auch mal eine Gaudi [Spaß] hat und zusammenhält, wenns drauf ankommt
>   - Wir zahlen nicht schlecht
>
> **Du:**
>   - magst [möchtest] etwas Neues machen, weil dich das Alte ankäst [langweilt]
>   - hast etwas gelernt, was mit dem Büro zu tun hat
>   - arbeitest gern und gut mit Leuten, Zahlen und Buchstaben
>   - denkst mit, organisierst gern, bist zuverlässig und nicht [leutscheu](http://www.ostarrichi.org/wort-13245-zuruckgezogen_lebend_den_Menschen_scheuen-leidschirch.html) [zurückgezogen, introvertiert]
>   - bist kein [Leimsieder](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/leimsieder-der/) [Langweiler], kein [Geschäfthuber](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gschaftlhuber) [Wichtigtuer] und kein [Zwiderwurzen](https://www.bayrisches-woerterbuch.de/zwiderwurzen-die/) [Griesgram]
>   - wohnst nicht ganz zu weit weg
>
> **Na, was sagst du?**
>   Wenn Dich das interessiert, dann ruf an oder schick uns gleich deine Papiere

Comment: Freu' mich sehr darüber, dass du dir die Mühe gemacht hast. Vielen Dank! - Eine Frage noch. Sehe ich das richtig, dass "Manschafd" im Original sowohl Plural als auch Singular ist? "- a guade Manschafd, di a ammoi a Gaudi ham und zammhoid, ..." - ... die auch mal eine Gaudi HABEN und zusammenHÄLT ?

Comment: Nein, das ist eigentlich ein Numerus-Fehler. Es müsste heißen "a guade Manschafd, die a ammoi a Gaudi *hod* und zammhoid".

Comment: @multiplex Ich kann kein Bairisch, aber es sieht für mich nach einem Fehler aus (Inkongruenz der Einzahl von *Mannschaft* und Plural von *haben*). Selbst wenn *Manschafd* auch Plural ist (was sein könnte), dann bliebe eine Inkongruenz mit *zammhoid* (falls das *zusammenhält* heißt). Allerdings **muss** *Manschafd* aufgrund des »a guade« Singular sein.

Answer (score 2):

> Firma sucht: für unseren Haufen: Eine(n) für's Büro.

Haufen: hier im Sinn von Gruppe/Team.

Answer (score 0):

In schöner Stellenanzeigen-Lyrik ergäbe das in etwa:

Zur Verstärkung unseres Teams suchen wir eine

### Bürokraft

Wir bieten:

- einen Arbeitsplatz, bei dem die Meinung des Mitarbeiters zählt
- Beschäftigungssicherheit (denn wir sind kein Wald- und Wiesenbetrieb)
- eine gute Einarbeitung
- eine abwechslungsreiche Tätigkeit für einen dankbaren Kundenstamm.

Förmlichkeiten liegen uns nicht, wir sind direkt, uns macht man nichts vor und das Wohl unserer Mitarbeiter liegt uns am Herzen.

(Weiterhin bieten wir)

- Teamgeist und gegenseitige Unterstützung
- Vergütung über Tarif.

Sie bieten:

- Interesse an einer neuen Herausforderung
- eine abgeschlossene Ausbildung im Bereich Büromanagement
- Einsatzfreude, Kommunikationsfähigkeit, sehr gutes Zahlenverständnis und sichere Beherrschung der Rechtschreibung
- Selbständigkeit, Organisationsstärke, Zuverlässigkeit und
  Sozialkompetenz

Sie haben Pep, machen aber nicht unnötig Wind, bringen gute Laune mit und wohnen in erreichbarer Nähe.

Nun, was sagen Sie?

Wenn sie interessiert sind, rufen Sie uns an, oder schicken uns gleich Ihre Bewerbungsunterlagen zu.

- Wir haben außerdem eine Lehrstelle (w/m) zu besetzen! -

[Da ich des Bairischen nicht mächtig bin, ist die Bedeutung einiger Stellen der Original-Anzeige eher erahnt als wirklich verstanden.]